# Webdriver: find element by html tag which contains an html tag which belongs to a certain class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

to clarify a really messy title: 
There is a piece of page code that looks like this (I have simplified the actual code):

```
<div class="CLASS1">
  <p>...
  <p>
    <strong>
      <i CLASS2 "></i>
      THE DATA I WANT
    </strong>
  </p>
  <p>...
  <p>...
</div>
```

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Java and I've been trying to get the `"DATA I WANT"` line, but since it is contained between  tags (and not the CLASS2 italic tag), I am having hard time accomplishing this. Note that the rest of the paragraphs (marked as `<p>...`) contain the analogous constructions. 
Currently it seems like searching for a CLASS1 `<strong>` tag that contains CLASS2 element `<i>` might be the solution, but I have not been able to compose a correct   search path so far. Now I am not sure if I am approaching this problem from a correct angle at all.
Any suggestions are greatly aprpeciated! I would like to have the shortest and the most reliable solution for this...

Comment: UPDATE: I've just discovered another important detail: the paragraph tag that contains the `<strong>` tag does not always come second in the order: sometimes the first paragraph block is absent, so the `<p>`that I am looking for may be the first in the line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the HTML you have posted. Following CSS selector should work.

```
div.CLASS1 > p:nth-child(2) > strong
```

If you need to get the the `strong` tag that contains `i.CLASS2` then you could do something like this.

```
// get all p tags
List<WebElement> pTags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.CLASS1 > p"));

WebElement myWebElement = null;

// iterate and find p tag that contains i.CLASS2
for (WebElement element : pTags) {
    if (element.findElements(By.cssSelector("i.CLASS2")).size() == 1) {
        myWebElement = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("strong"));
        break;
    }
}

// the data you want
System.out.println(myWebElement.getText());
```

Comment: you should break when find the desired element :)

Comment: I figured that out, but appreciate your effort on improving the answer :)